# Page transitions using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, transition

I'm need to create a slide transition effect using JQuery when switching pages.  However, I'm not entirely sure how to get started.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?  If there is already an existing plugin that does this, can you point that out as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is a well supported library that does this sort of thing. That would be a good place to look, and might even do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very very simple solution.  It keeps the pages you are wanting to cycle through in an array and the get next/prev links will just go through them.

HTML:

```
<a href = '#' id = 'getPrev'>Get Prev</a>
<div id = 'contentArea'></div>
<a href = '#' id = 'getNext'>Get Next</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var pages = array( "one.html", "two.html", "three.html" );
var curPage = 0;

$(function() {
    $("#getPrev").bind("click", function() {
        $("#contentArea").fadeOut();
        curPage--;
        if(curPage < 0) curPage = pages.length-1
        fetchPage(pages[curPage]);
    });
});

function fetchPage(page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: page,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#contentArea").html(html).fadeIn();
        }, 
        error: function(a,b,c) {  $("#contentArea").html("An Error Occured.").fadeIn(); }
    });
}
```

The binding for 'getNext' link would be similar, except the direction you are going in.